# Does the application gateway firewall function only on the application layer or on all layers of the OSI model?

Tags: firewalls, proxy

This is very confusing. I am seeing 2 different things in various books and sites.

A. Application gateway firewall scans layer 1 to layer 7 of the OSI model.

B. Application gateway firewall only scans Application Layer (Or Application, Presentation and Session Layer) data.

I asked many people and they, also, were not too sure about it.

[image: This figure doesn't help with the confusion]

Comment: When referencing what books and sites say, it is always helpful to provide links.

Answer (score 0):

An application layer firewall has the ability to analyze the application layer and will do the majority of analysis at this layer. This means it will analyze application payload and might also do TLS inspection. But it often also makes decisions based on IP addresses and ports (layers 3 and 4) - typically though in the context of the application, like the reputation of a specific IP address regarding sending spam or malware in the context of mail delivery.

Layers 1 and 2 are typically not analyzed though, since there is usually nothing relevant there for analysis.

Apart from that, note that the OSI model does not reflect today's reality very well. Layers 5-7 can not usually be clearly separated and are often merged together. The [TCP/IP model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) is more suitable here.

Comment: I've few question:

1) Even packet filtering f/w looks at IP address and Port Number, so what's different in Application g/w f/w?

2) Are L1 & L2 not analyzed by any f/w OR not only by application g/w f/w?

3) https://imgur.com/a/qae6gdM

When we say something operates at "this" layer, does it scans all the layers below it? Or just the layer at "that level"? This is really a confusing question for me! (I'm aware that we could tweak any f/w to work like an f/w, but I want the formal first principle design)

Comment: @zeeshanseikh: 1) that ALG **also** look at the application layer, not only at network and transport layer. 2) L1 has no relevant security properties from the perspective of FW. L2 is primarily relevant in the local network and might be used by FW doing microsegmentation in the local network or by switches doing port security. 3) Of course they need the lower layers to work, but the problems they are supposed to solve are only at the layers mentioned.